# Selecting rows with max value in range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the followng data:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
| id | site_id |      datetime       | views |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-11-01 23:59:59 |    12 |
|  2 |       1 | 2013-11-02 23:59:59 |    15 |
|  3 |       1 | 2013-11-03 23:59:59 |    18 |
|  4 |       1 | 2013-11-04 23:59:59 |    29 |
|  5 |       1 | 2013-11-05 23:59:59 |    38 |
|  6 |       1 | 2013-11-05 12:59:59 |    40 |
|  7 |       1 | 2013-11-06 23:59:59 |    45 |
|  8 |       1 | 2013-11-07 23:59:59 |    49 |
|  9 |       1 | 2013-11-08 23:59:59 |    52 |
| 10 |       2 | 2013-11-04 23:59:59 |    25 |
| 11 |       2 | 2013-11-05 21:59:59 |    42 |
| 12 |       2 | 2013-11-06 23:59:59 |    60 |
| 13 |       2 | 2013-11-07 23:59:59 |    75 |
| 14 |       2 | 2013-11-08 23:59:59 |    86 |
| 15 |       2 | 2013-11-09 23:59:59 |    90 |
| 16 |       2 | 2013-11-10 23:59:59 |    92 |
| 17 |       2 | 2013-11-11 23:42:59 |    98 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
```

I would pass a day and wish to get the rows with the highest time in the given day or if there`s no records for this site for this day, the last available row in the past.

e.g. for `2013-11-01`

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
| id | site_id |      datetime       | views |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-11-01 23:59:59 |    12 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
```

for `2013-11-05`

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
| id | site_id |      datetime       | views |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
|  5 |       1 | 2013-11-05 23:59:59 |    38 |
| 11 |       2 | 2013-11-05 21:59:59 |    42 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
```

and for `2013-11-10`

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
| id | site_id |      datetime       | views |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
|  9 |       1 | 2013-11-08 23:59:59 |    52 |
| 16 |       2 | 2013-11-10 23:59:59 |    92 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example for 2013-11-10 is wrong. Please just delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```sql
SELECT a.id,a.site_id,b.maxDate,a.views
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  site_id ,MAX(datetime) as maxDate
    FROM table1
    WHERE datetime < DATEYOUWANTTOSEE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY site_id
) b ON a.site_id = b.site_id AND a.datetime = b.maxDate
```

The inner query will get you the MAX(datetime) for each site_id. Then you join it with your table to get the rest of the information.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b782/1)</kbd>

Comment: I would use `WHERE datetime < DATEYOUWANTTOSE + INTERVAL 1 DAY` so indexes can be used - i.e. an index on `(site_id, datetime)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE datetime = <datetime> ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I think he is looking for a bit more generic statement, i.e. he doesn't know the datetime value, he wants to collect all of them

Comment: this is an mysql query and the syntax i have wrote is correct , ok

Comment: This won't give him the max datetime for each id. It will give him the  two records with the biggest date for that day. And if there's no records for that day will not give any results.

Comment: then he need to control this programmatically in conditions. and if there is no result from the above query i wrote he need to execute another one which will give him h max datetime in just past.

Comment: SELECT * FROM <tablename> where datetime < <datetime> ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: SQL can do that for him. But yes. he could do some stuff in his programming language to achieve this. But the LIMIT 2 is always going to be wrong. because you may have two records for the same site_id. And if you have 200 site_id's, it will not be very helpful.

Comment: yes, but he did not specify the constraints in the question, as i can see he only wants highest , so two records are enough.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`datetime`, 1, 10) AS date, MAX(`views`)
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`datetime`, 1, 10)
```

If you need the id/site_id as well, write it in your post, as it is not clear

SQLFiddle to show you the result:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ccb3/1

Comment: SQLfiddle is down, so I cannot show you it in "live" environment

Comment: The OP wants `GROUP BY site_id`, not `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)` (and using string functions is not the best practice when there are datetime functions available.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, where did he write please group it by site_id ?

Comment: The examples show that (and the not so clear *"... or if there`s no records for **this site** for this day..."*)

Answer (score -2):

You data and examples do not really match themselves, nor the description, but what you probably are looking for is this:

```
Select top 1 * 
  from table
 where date(datetime) <= date(@PARAMETER)
```

order by datetime desc

Comment: Your indentation is a bit off.

Comment: It's tagged with MySQL